# Como resolver exceção de Stackoverflow que ocorre no Mapemento da Entidade para a Model?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, fluent-api

Em minha aplicação uma Equipe possui vários usuários e um Usuário pertence somente à uma Equipe (1:N), sendo assim tenho as seguintes entidades:

```
public class Equipe{

     public Guid EquipeId {get; set;}
     public string Nome {get; set;}
     public virtual ICollection<Usuario> Usuarios {get; set;}

     public Equipe(){
          EquipeId = Guid.NewGuid();
          Usuarios = new List<Usuarios>();
      }
}

public class Usuario{

     public Guid UsuarioId {get; set;}
     public string Nome {get; set;}

     public Guid EquipeId {get; set;}
     public virtual Equipe {get; set;}

     public Usuario(){
          UsuariosId = Guid.NewGuid();
          Equipe = new Equipe();
     }
}
```

Nas configurações da entidade Equipe estou usando o seguinte código:

```
public class EquipeConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Equipe>{

   public EquipeConfig(){

          ToTables("Equipes");

          HasKey(x => x.EquipeId);

          Property(x => x.Nome)
               .IsRequired().
               .HasMaxLenght(250);

         HasMany(x => x.Usuarios)
               .WithRequired(c => c.Equipe)
               .HasForeingKey(x => x.EquipeId);
   }
}
```

Porem quando faço a seguinte consulta no repositório para obter todos os usuários e as suas respectivas equipes, tenho esta exceção no momento em que o `Mapper` tenta realizar o mapeamento para a `Model`:

> Stackoverflow Exception

```
//método do repositório
public ICollection<Usuarios> ObtenhaTodosUsuarios()
      => Context.Usuarios.Include(c => c.Equipe).ToList();

//método da Application      
public ICollection<UsuarioModel> ObtenhaTodosUsuarios(){

      var result = _UsuarioRepositorio.ObtenhaTodosUsuarios();

      return Mapper.Map<ICollection<UsuarioModel>>(result); //exceção

}
```

No contexto as seguintes configurações no construtor:

```
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

E no override `OnModelCreating`

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();                
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();                
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

Comment: Onde você criou a regra de mapeamento? Pelo que vi você está utilizando AutoMapper, correto?

Comment: Minha opinião: Se você adicionar a Entidade `Usuarios` e `UsuarioModel` e como foi feito o mapeamento na pergunta fica mais simples de te ajudar. Acho que os 3 bastariam pra responder a sua pergunta.